# How can I use the InStr function to search and highlight a value in a multiline textbox?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, highlighting

I am attempting to create a search inside of a multiline textbox that will find each instance of a value and highlight that value inside the textbox. It will need to work regardless of how many instances exist on a given line. So far I have used the following code to identify if a value exists on a line but cannot get the highlighting to work properly when there are multiple instances of the same value.

```
strVal = "Find Me"
arrLines =Split(myTextbox.value, vbCrLf)
For Each strLine In arrLines
     If InStr(strVal, myTextbox.text) > 0 Then
          myTextbox.SelStart = InStr(strVal, my textbox.value)
           myTextbox.SelLength = Len(strVal)
           Exit For
    End if
 Next
```

I want to have this macro linked to a button and have the macro find and highlight the next instance each time the button is clicked regardless if that instance is on the same line or a new line. Basically, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> feature for the textbox. Thanks!

Comment: Read this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx. It will get the same job done, but not using InStr Function. after using the FindAll you can apply `Interior.ColorIndex` to highlight the cell

Comment: That is an interesting technique but I don't see how I can make this work in a userform textbox. This method is for worksheet objects.

Comment: Is this a form textbox? I am not sure about highlighting non-contiguous blocks of text - have you seen this somewhere?

Comment: You don't need to split the lines in order to find the start position.  Note - `instr()` has an optional `start` parameter to allow you to specify where to begin looking inside the string: use a global variable to keep track of the previous position of a hit, and adjust the value accordingly.

Comment: I was able to make your solution work after adding the split lines. The reason the split line is necessary is due to the instanceposition shifting by one space each time you go to a new line. I added a counter after the shift line and subtract the counter from the instanceposition if the counter is greater than 1. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this code a try (see comments for explanations):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Static lastInstancePosition As Long ' use Static variable to have its value persist after Sub exiting
    Dim instancePosition As Long

    strVal = "Find me"
    With myTextbox
        instancePosition = InStr(lastInstancePosition + 1, .Text, strVal) 'search string occurrence starting from last found item
        If instancePosition > 0 Then
            .SetFocus 'bring focus back ti the textbox after it has been taken by the button
            .SelStart = instancePosition - 1
            .SelLength = Len(strVal)
            lastInstancePosition = instancePosition ' update starting position for next search
       End If
    End With
End Sub
```